# Symfony fos:user:create through error "could not find driver", (Xampp with multiple verison of PHP)

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, fosuserbundle

- **INTRODUCTION:**

I am in a Symfony Project with PHPStorm. I'm trying to create a fos user on DB (xampp MySQL).

Symfony CLI version v4.21.6
Composer version 1.10.19

```
C:\Program Files\Symfony\name_projectFolder>php -v
PHP 8.0.0 (cli)

C:\Program Files\Symfony\name_projectFolder>symfony php -v
PHP 7.4.14 (cli)
```

With the first command we see the actual php version (8.0.0) that is used by default, but my project doesn't support it, so i installed another one (on xampp folder with the correct procedure) and told to the project to use this new version (7.4.14) instead of the default one.

TO SET which php version the project should use:

```
C:\Program Files\Symfony\name_projectFolder>echo 7.4 > .php-version
```

TO SEE the list of PHP versions that we have:

```
C:\Program Files\Symfony\name_projectFolder>symfony local:php:list
```

[image: screenshot - result of the command "symfony local:php:list"]

The **highlighted number** on the left is the actual version that the project is using.
The asterisk on the right indicates the default system PHP version.

(**INFO**:
If you want to use a normal command you need to specify which PHP version it should refer to, in order to  run it.
To do so just add before the normal command the "symfony" word because it will use the project settings and not the system ones.)

- **START** with the procedure to CREATE the fos user:

(as we said before, we use the word "symfony" to "tell" to the command to use the 7.4 PHP version, keep in mind that normally you don't to this)

```
C:\Program Files\Symfony\name_projectFolder>symfony php bin\console fos:user:create
```

you'll **get this error**:
[image: screenshot - error showed]

in a few words `"An exception occurred in driver: could not find driver"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION**

Because you have two PHP versions, in the new one you need to enable the pdo_mysql extension that normaly is not.

STOP the Apache Server in the XAMPP controller.

just go in the folder `C:\xampp\php7_4` and open the file `php.ini`

search (CTRL+F) for **pdo_mysql** and uncomment/remove the "**;**"

*BEFORE*  `;extension=pdo_mysql`

*AFTER*   `extension=pdo_mysql`

SAVE the changes

START the Apache Server and re-run the `symfony php bin\console fos:user:create` command and it will work !!